# How can I return differences between versions and access properties that changed?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, csom, splistitem

i have a list in SharePoint 2010 that has fields "title,count" .one of the fields (count) possible to change.

i want to access the last version of this property. by this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408687/programatically-get-listitem-by-version-using-cleint-object-model-sharepoint-201?rq=1): but there are no accepted answer yet.

```
            File file;
            FileVersionCollection versions;
            ClientContext clientContext;
            IEnumerable<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion> oldVersions;

            clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, shp.domainname);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            string path = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + listname + "/" + id1 + "_.000";  // it represet list id 7
            file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(path);

            ListItem versionListItem = file.ListItemAllFields;

            clientContext.Load(versionListItem);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            versions = file.Versions;
            clientContext.Load(versions);
            oldVersions = clientContext.LoadQuery(versions.Where(v => v != null));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            if (oldVersions != null)
            {
                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion _version in oldVersions)
                {
                     DateTime date = new DateTime();
                     date = _version.Created.Date;
```

here i can access to properties but "count" doesn't exist here.

i want to have differences by last versions like SharePoint

[image: sharepoint 2010 show version history and diffrences]

i have other method (find it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8147b181-1810-4aa6-b4d9-4273eeaab938/how-to-get-file-versions-metadata-using-the-client-object?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) ) that return for me those last property values

```
  ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://basesmc2008");
  Web site = clientContext.Web;
  clientContext.Load(site);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

  File file = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents/test.tif");
  clientContext.Load(file);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

  ListItem currentItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
  clientContext.Load(currentItem);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


  FileVersionCollection versions = file.Versions;
  IEnumerable<FileVersion> oldVersions = clientContext.LoadQuery(versions.Where(v => v.VersionLabel == "1.0"));
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


  if (oldVersions != null)
  {
  foreach (FileVersion oldFileVersion in oldVersions)
  {


     File oldFile = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/" + oldFileVersion.Url);
     clientContext.Load(oldFile);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

     ListItem oldItem = oldFile.ListItemAllFields;
     clientContext.Load(oldItem);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();         
     //error here
  }
```

error here

> An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Value does not fall within
>   the expected range

**is there any solution shorter than this for retrieve all last values of specific field?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly actual version data is not available from CSOM. You can get the data by extracting it from */_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={[THE LIST ID]}&ID=[THE ITEMID]&IsDlg=1*;

I used HTMLAgilityPack to parse out the data I was looking for (a past value for a specific field)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(DownloadedPageContent);

HtmlNodeCollection n = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@id='vv" + VersionId + FieldName +"']/td");

String value = n[1].InnerText.Trim();
```

Comment: how can i believe that Microsoft has not any tools   ?? or  any way to implement that by programming? thanks for this solution . intelligence method.